# Create bulk Monero addresses

Tags: integrated-address

How can i create multiple Monero addresses?

anyway to make 1000+ Monero addresses at once.

Any tools/ software c an be used?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? I ask because maybe there is a better way to achieve your goal.

Comment: I agree with pl55 that you should explain why you want to do this, as your goal might be better accomplished some other way, but if you really want this can be done trivially with Python or another scripting language.

Answer (score 2):

An easy scriptable way is to run:

> for n in `seq 1000`; do ./monero-wallet-cli --generate-new-wallet wallet$n; done

It's a bit heavyweight though. If you can code, you can generate new keypairs with:

```
cryptonote::account_base account;
account.generate();
account_public_address address = account.get_keys().m_account_address;
```